# android @Nullable annotation

Tags: android

I want to create

> android @Nullable annotation

i check this two links for example

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/Nullable.html
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/UseNullable

but none works in android because RetentionPolicy, ElementType is not valid

How can i create @Nullable annotation in android?

Comment: not sure but android has one here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Nullable.html

Answer (score 2):

Include `jsr-305` [`jar` file](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.findbugs/jsr305/1.3.2) in project libraries. Use `@nullable` with fields and RoboGuice will stop complaining about null objects.

Comment: I try but hmm is the same.I can not create this notation that will work as it must

Answer (score 2):

For Android Studio:

- Add the following to **build.gradle**:

  ```
  dependencies {
      ...
      // For @Nullable/@NonNull
      compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
  }
  ```
- Go to **File** / **Setting** → **Project Settings** → **Inspections** and search for "nullable".

  In **Constant conditions & exceptions** and **@NotNull/@Nullable problems**, click **Configure annotations** and select Android's annotations.

  You may also want to check **Suggest @Nullable annotations…** under **Constant conditions & exceptions**, or possibly tweak other options.