# IDE independant @Nullable annotation

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

After detecting a NPE while testing, I finally wanted to take a look at `@Nullable` annotations.

After a small internet search there seems to be a `@Nullable` annotation for every IDE or environment:

- [Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_type_annotations.htm)
- [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotating-source-code.html)
- [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/Nullable.html)
- [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200701/android-nullable-annotation)
- [Firebugs (javax.annotation.Nullable)](https://dzone.com/articles/findbugs-and-jsr-305)
- ... probably others

I have seen that they seem all to follow [JSR-305](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305), which describes this annotation.
But the JSR is dormant, see also: [What is the status of JSR 305?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289694/what-is-the-status-of-jsr-305).

So I have two questions:

- Is there another general annotation which can be used?
- If no, do the IDEs only recognize their own annotations.

  - E.g. would it be possible to use the Spring annotations in a non-Spring-project, and Eclipse and IntelliJ can handle the annotation correctly.

Comment: What about `javax.annotation.Nullable` ?

Comment: I did not know about that specific annotation and added it to the list.
Unfortunately Eclipse and SonarLint ignore it.

Comment: Oh! But SolarLint works with `javax.annotation.CheckForNull`. As actually pointed out in S2259 and the Javadoc of `javax.annotation.Nullable`.
But Eclipse still ignores it.
 @Stewart: Thank you for the hint

Comment: Eclipse can be set up to work with any Nullable annotation, check under Java / Compiler / Errors-Warnings / Null Analysis. Long-term, there's going to be https://jspecify.dev/ which is a joint project to finally come up with a single spec and a single set of annotations, and it is worked on by multiple projects, companies, IDEs. Not there yet, it's in a very early stage, so not prod-ready, but take a look in a year or two. Until then, `javax.annotation.Nullable` is where it's at unless you prefer a different one for the small semantic differences they have,

Comment: Oh, also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use, it's a mess. IDEs can be set-up to use whichever annotation, though. Or, use a checker like NullAway.

Comment: @PetrJaneček Thank you: I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As I happen to use SonarLint/SonarQube the following works independently of the IDE.

For a Maven project one can add the JSR-305 annotations provided by Findbugs.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency
```

Then the needed methods can be annotated with `@CheckForNull`.
According to the [`@Nullable`-Javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/latest/javax/annotation/Nullable.html) static analysis tools should ignore the `@Nullable` annotation.

If the method return value is then used without a preceding null-check, SonarLint raises a [`Null pointers should not be dereferenced (java:S2259)`](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2259) issue.

Eclipse ignores this by default, but as Petr Janeček pointed out it can be configured to use the annotation.
If `javax.annotation.CheckForNull` or `javax.annotation.Nullable` should be used is probably debatable.

[image: Eclipse settings]

I have not tested this for other IDEs.

Comment: The answer does not need the ugly import of `spring-core` any more.

Comment: According to your screenshot you configured the wrong annotation: first has to be `javax.annotation.Nullable`. Please note, as far as I known, only the _org.eclipse.jdt_ null annotations do not pollute the bytecode.

Comment: This is what I meant with "If javax.annotation.CheckForNull or javax.annotation.Nullable should be used is probably debatable."
I think that `javax.annotation.CheckForNull` equals `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable` according to their respective Javadoc.
`javax.annotation.Nullable` is (according to it's Javadoc) only a hint for the developer.

Till now I have not yet considered comparing the bytecode, as I added the annotations only in the `compile`-scope.
But it is an interesting point.